# Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program Visual Studio 2010

Tags: .net, visual-studio, opencv, out-of-memory, emgucv

I was running my computer vision project which is implemented in EmguCV(.Net Wrapper to the OpenCV) in Visual Studion 2010 (in C#). It was calculating my features from images for training and save them in a float array. After about one day of running, this error is appeared:

```
OutOfMemoryException was unhandled
Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program
```

As my Training Set is too big, 
how can I save these features in an array? considering that It was less than half of my program that I got this error and my array will have much more data.

the size of my array is now {float[199897, 88]}, is it normal that I get this error?

Comment: You said it's *now* 17.5m floats. How and when do you resize it? What does your code look like? Does your memory rise continually up to that point?

Comment: This is obvious. The problem is not your data array. Make sure your memory management is robust. Since EmguCV works with unmanaged resources, it is extremely important to carefully check your implementation for lacking calls to `Dispose()`. Furthermore, if you're constantly allocating new large data arrays (e.g. `byte[] data = new byte[1000000]`), your LOH (large objects heap) gets under memory pressure, so the exception is thrown.